# Adding a backspace button to a Python GUI Calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I'm making a GUI calculator in python using tkinter. The calculator works very and now i would like to add a backspace function so that it clears the last number on the display. For example 321 would become 32. I've tried defining a function 'backspace' and the 'bind_all' method but I'm not too entirely sure how they work resulting in an error message. If anyone could kindly show me how to go about this and explain it, it would be most grateful.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

def quit ():
root.destroy()
# the main class
class Calc():
def __init__(self):
    self.total = 0
    self.current = ""
    self.new_num = True
    self.op_pending = False
    self.op = ""
    self.eq = False

#setting the variable when the number is pressed
def num_press(self, num):
    self.eq = False
    temp = text_box.get()
    temp2 = str(num)
    if self.new_num:
        self.current = temp2
        self.new_num = False

    else:
        if temp2 == '.':
            if temp2 in temp:
                return
        self.current = temp + temp2
    self.display(self.current)



# event=None to use function in command= and in binding
def clearLastDigit(self, event=None):
    current = self.text_box.get()[:-1]
    self.text_box.delete(0, END)
    self.text_box.current(INSERT, text)


def calc_total(self):
    self.eq = True
    self.current = float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending == True:
        self.do_sum()
    else:
        self.total = float(text_box.get())

#setting up the text display area
def display(self, value):
    text_box.delete(0, END)
    text_box.insert(0, value)


#Opperations Button
def do_sum(self):
    if self.op == "add":
        self.total += self.current
    if self.op == "minus":
        self.total -= self.current
    if self.op == "times":
        self.total *= self.current
    if self.op == "divide":
        self.total /= self.current
    self.new_num = True
    self.op_pending = False
    self.display(self.total)

def operation(self, op):
    self.current = float(self.current)
    if self.op_pending:
        self.do_sum()
    elif not self.eq:
        self.total = self.current
    self.new_num = True
    self.op_pending = True
    self.op = op
    self.eq = False

#Clear last entry
def cancel(self):
    self.eq = False
    self.current = "0"
    self.display(0)
    self.new_num = True

#Clear all entries
def all_cancel(self):
    self.cancel()
    self.total = 0

#backspace button
def backspace(self):
    self.cancel()
    self.display(len(self.text_box.get())-1)


#Changing the Sign (+/-)
def sign(self):
    self.eq = False
    self.current = -(float(text_box.get()))
    self.display(self.current)



#Global Varibles that are used within Attributes
sum1 = Calc()
root = Tk()
calc = Frame(root)
calc.grid()

#Creating the window for the calculator
root.title("Calculator")
text_box = Entry(calc, justify=RIGHT)
text_box.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3, pady = 5)
text_box.insert(0, "0")

#buttons 1-9 (Displayed row by row)
numbers = "789456123"
i = 0
bttn = []
for j in range(1,4):
for k in range(3):
    bttn.append(Button(calc, text = numbers[i], width= 5, height = 2, bg="#fe0000"))
    bttn[i].grid(row = j, column = k)
    bttn[i]["command"] = lambda x = numbers[i]: sum1.num_press(x)
    i += 1
#button 0
bttn_0 = Button(calc, text = "0", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#fe0000")
bttn_0["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(0)
bttn_0.grid(row = 4, column = 1, pady = 5)

#button / (Divide)
bttn_div = Button(calc, text = chr(247), width= 5, height = 2, bg="#00b0f0" )
bttn_div["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("divide")
bttn_div.grid(row = 1, column = 3, pady = 5)

#button x (Times)
bttn_mult = Button(calc, text = "x", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#00b0f0")
bttn_mult["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("times")
bttn_mult.grid(row = 2, column = 3, pady = 5)

#button - (Minus)
minus = Button(calc, text = "-", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#00b0f0")
minus["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("minus")
minus.grid(row = 4, column = 3, pady = 5)

#button + (Plus)
add = Button(calc, text = "+", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#00b0f0")
add["command"] = lambda: sum1.operation("add")
add.grid(row = 3, column = 3, pady = 5)

#button + or - (Plus/minus)
neg= Button(calc, text = "+/-", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#7030a0")
neg["command"] = sum1.sign
neg.grid(row = 5, column = 0, pady = 5)

#button Clear (Clear)
clear = Button(calc, text = "C", width= 5, height = 2, bg="yellow")
clear["command"] = sum1.cancel
clear.grid(row = 5, column = 1, pady = 5)

#button All Clear ( All Clear)
all_clear = Button(calc, text = "CE", width= 5, height = 2, bg="yellow")
all_clear["command"] = sum1.all_cancel
all_clear.grid(row = 5, column = 2, pady = 5)

#button . (Decimal)
point = Button(calc, text = ".", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#c00000")
point["command"] = lambda: sum1.num_press(".")
point.grid(row = 4, column = 0, pady = 5)

#button = (Equals)
equals = Button(calc, text = "=", width= 5, height = 2, bg="#7030a0")
equals["command"] = sum1.calc_total
equals.grid(row = 4, column = 2, pady = 5)

#button Quit
quit_bttn = Button(calc, text ="Quit", width=5, height = 2, bg="green")
quit_bttn["command"] = quit
quit_bttn.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

#button BackSpace
backspace_bttn = Button(calc, text = "Backspace", width= 15, height = 2, bg="yellow")
backspace_bttn["command"] = sum1.backspace
backspace_bttn.grid(row = 6, column = 0, columnspan = 4)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @furas this was the error I was getting
`line 106, in backspace
    self.display(len(self.text_box.get())-1)
AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'text_box'`

Comment: In oryginal version (see link in my answer) All buttons were inside class and there was `self.text_box` but you have all outside class so you have `text_box` instead of `self.text_box`

Comment: If you have code outside of class you should resign of using class and move all functions (with some modifications) from class to outside. Some one could ask "Why do you put some functions inside class and others outside? Do you really know how to use classes ?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show error message - probably you have problem with number of arguments. `bind_all` call function with two arguments `backspace(self, event)`, `command` call function only with one argument `backspace(self)`

See my comment in your code before `def clearLastDigit(self, event=None):`

```
# event=None to use function in command= and in binding
```

To use `backspace` with `command=` you need

```
def backspace(self):
    self.cancel()
    self.display(len(self.text_box.get())-1)
```

To use `backspace` with `bind_all` you need

```
def backspace(self, event):
    self.cancel()
    self.display(len(self.text_box.get())-1)
```

By the way:

`len(self.text_box.get())-1` give you text length minus 1.  if you need sorter text (321 -> 32) use `self.display(  self.text_box.get()[:-1]  )`

---

See calculator with backspace in answer to [How do I backspace and clear the last equation and also a quit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20319434/1832058)

---

**EDIT:** For `command` you have to change only `backspace(self)` to this

```
def backspace(self):
    text = text_box.get()[:-1]
    if text == "":
        text = "0"
    self.current = text
    self.display( text )
```

Maybe it needs some other changes to get correct results in some special situations.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So if i was to use the Command approach, how would i do it.

Comment: For Command you need to change `backspace()` see new code in answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Code is working fine now. You mentioned something about fixing the class, can you explain what I could do to improve it. Thanks

Comment: Teacher can ask "why do you put only part of code in class? Why don't you put all code in class?" The best solution is to put all in class - see example in my answer to [How do I backspace and clear the last equation and also a quit button?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20319434/1832058) - all code is in class except last line where I create class instance and I use `run()` to start `mainloop`.

Comment: So to put everything in the same class, would indent everything from `#Global Varibles that are used within Attributes` down?

Comment: Global variables have to be in class as atrributes (you can create it in `__init__` using `self.`) and then you use `self.variable_name` to access it in all functions/methods in class.